# Problem in app after hitting the back button (Wifi state)

Tags: java, android, methods, wifi, android-wifi

Problem Description:

my app has a main window. when you click a button it make sure you are connected to wifi or 3g, if not it pop up a dialog that enables wifi.
when wifi is on and the button is clicked a new screen shows up. when you hit the back button, disable wifi and click that button again it does not ask for wifi again and the screen shows up without wifi....

In the Click event of the button i have:

```
 if(chosedOption == curOption)
            {
                if(network)
                {
                    target = CurrencyMain.class;
                    go.setAnimation(a);
                }
                else
                    askForWifi();
            }
```

and in the askForWifi method i have:

```
public void askForWifi()
 {
    is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
    isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected();
    network = is3g||isWifi;
     if(!network)
        {    
         AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindowYuval.this).create();
         alertbox.setMessage("Enable wifi of 3g!");
         alertbox.setButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                    dialog.dismiss();                      
                }  
            });  

         alertbox.setButton2("Turn wifi on", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainWindowYuval.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);                     
                }  
            });

         alertbox.show();

        }
        is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
        isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected();
        network = is3g||isWifi;

 }
```

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: should you not check for WiFi before invoking the second screen?

Comment: thats what i do, i check for wifi, if there is, i set the animation which then invoke the screen

Comment: got to be missing something. where do you invoke the second screen?

Comment: OnAnimationEnd:

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainWindowYuval.this, target);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); 
      startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to update value of `network` before making decision whether to invoke the second screen. Something like:

```
askForWiFi();
if(network){
   invoke...
}else{
   go to settings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check for WiFi in the second screen instead? If it's not there, ask them to enable it there *or* send them back to the home screen.

Comment: Thats a bit of a problem because the second screen must have wifi enabled for the user to be able to do something. But anyway thats avoiding the problem...why is it doing this?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. Where is the value of `network` coming from? You should try to see if that value changes back to false once you disable WiFi. Is that value modified *only* in your `askForWifi()` method?